# Is there a design pattern/system for lazy loading bundled AMD modules without loading modules I've already downloaded?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, amd

Suppose I have a large single-page application which is built around AMD modules. When the user first visits the front page of this application, we want the initial JS payload to be reasonably light so we only load the minimum JS to set up the app and load the front page. From there the user can do "Action A" or "Action B". Each "action" requires new modules (`"module_a"` and `"module_b"` repectively) to be loaded.

`module_a`'s dependencies are `module_a_1`, `module_a_2`, `module_a_3`, and `module_X`
`module_b`'s dependencies are `module_b_1`, `module_b_2`, `module_b_3`, and `module_X`

Notice that both modules depend on `module_X`.

Now, if the user performs "Action A" we tell the server we want `module_a`. The server bundles `module_a` and all of its dependencies into the response. If the user performs "Action A" again, the client knows we already have `module_a` so it doesn't have to download anything new. That's easy.

But suppose the user performs "Action A" and a little while later, performs "Action B". Clearly we need to download `module_b`, `module_b_1`, etc. **but the client already has `module_X`**. It would be a shame if `module_X` came bundled with the request for `module_b` because we already have `module_X`.

Is there a system/framework/pattern that supports the requesting AMD modules and their dependencies but not the dependencies the client already has, perhaps by somehow communicating to the server the modules the client has?

Comment: When you load the module you can send the list of modules you've already fetched before; the server will then generate the minimal set. Otherwise the knowledge of what goes into each module must be leaked into the client code.

Comment: have you looked at requireJS?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a system/framework/pattern that supports the requesting AMD modules and their dependencies but not the dependencies the client already has, perhaps by somehow communicating to the server the modules the client has?

It seems you're missing the point of AMD, since that's exactly what it does -- if `module_X` is already loaded, there will not be another request to the server for `module_X`.

Reading between the lines of the question, I think you're not stating it properly. I think the situation is this:

You're not specifying all the module dependencies at the beginning of your module definition. Using nested inner requires, you're lazy loading some dependencies until the moment that they're needed. As a result, what you find is that the inner require loads dependencies you've already declared as part of your outer dependency, or as part of another inner require dependency.

If this is the problem, then the short answer is that the nested require needs the loading context of the outer require. This is done by specifying `require` itself as a dependency

```
require(["require", /* other deps */], function(require, ...){
   require(["module_a_1","module_X"], function(moda1,modx){ /*... */});
   require(["module_b_1","module_X"], function(modb1,modx){ /*... */});
}
```

This isn't very well documented in RequireJS's own documentation. See https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/173 for more details.